# How do I run a function from a list of values in an SQL Query?

Tags: sql, function

I have an SQL function that takes a number and returns values based on it. Say it is called my_function(@RefNumber).

I want to run the function several times based on the results of another query. There is a parent child relationship in the table and I want to run the function for every child number in the parent number.

So with a table like:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 4 |
| 100 | 5 |

With the example table above, I would want to ask the function to run 5 times based on my passing the parent number 100 into it, each time setting the @RefNumber as the next corresponding child number
I would say for each child in parent 100, run my_function so

my_function(1), my_function(2) ... and so on until my_function(5)

Appreciate any help with this. I'm assuming I need some kind of loop and set function.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what does the function do?  In particular, does it return a value or a result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can run a *scalar* function as:

```
select t.*,
       my_function(child)
from t
 where parent = 100;
```

If your function is a *table-valued* function in SQL Server you can use `apply`:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     dbo.my_function(child)
 where parent = 100;
```

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. I thought you had to always use a declared variable within the function and have to loop through setting it. It's very handy to know that I can pass the record into the function without 'setting'. Thanks again.